# Calculate 1.5 overtime pay hit invalid arithmetic operator error

Tags: bash

I'm trying to calculate 1.5 overtime pay for employee but having syntax error "invalid arithmetic operator". Do I need to indicate any special command for decimal calculation?
Thanks.

Error:

```
Enter employee name: Mary
Mary is Hourly employee.
Enter hourly wage:1
Enter hours worked this week:42
./Assignment2.sh: line 196: let: hwages = (40 * hsalary) + (overtime * 1.5 * hsalary): syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5 * hsalary)")
Gross wages: $
Hit [Enter] to return to main menu...
```

My code:

```
   elif [ "$EmployeeType" = "Hourly" ]
   then
    echo -en "Enter hourly wage:"
    read hsalary
    echo -en "Enter hours worked this week:"
    read hours
    if [ "$hours" > 40 ]
    then
    let "overtime = hours - 40"
    let "hwages = (40 * hsalary) + (overtime * 1.5 * hsalary)"
    else
    let "hwages = hsalary * hours"
    fi
    echo -en "Gross wages: \$$hwages"
    echo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BASH only support integer arithmetic and doesn't support floating point arithmetic. Use `bc -l` or `awk`

Example:

```
bc -l <<< "1.5 * 20"
30.0
```

Comment: tried let "hwages = (40 * hsalary) + (overtime * 1.5 * hsalary)" | bc. It doesn't work.. What am I missing?

Comment: Provide your full updated script in your question so that I can investigate and suggest.

Comment: You need to use this command: **`hwages=$(bc -l <<< "(40 * $hsalary) + ($overtime * 1.5 * $hsalary)")`**

Comment: I get this error. let: hwages=43.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")

Comment: As I wrote BASH doesn't support floating point arithmetic so you can't do `let hwages=43.0`

Comment: The given script is most likely to work in `zsh`, after applying the 4th comment